# No module named 'gcp_sql_operator' in cloud composer

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-composer

I am not able to import statement as-

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcp_sql_operator import CloudSqlQueryOperator
```

I want to import this in my DAG file which will be run in cloud composer airflow whose version is 1.10.0 and not 1.9.0.Here just to check, I tried to import gcs_to_gcs as-

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_gcs import GoogleCloudStorageToGoogleCloudStorageOperator
```

I am able to import this but not gcp_sql_operator.

Answer (score 5):

The `CloudSqlQueryOperator` operator is released since Airflow [1.10.2](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.2/airflow/contrib/operators/gcp_sql_operator.py), which is currently not supported in [Composer versions](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/release-notes). The support for 1.10.2 should be available soon in Composer, before that you may want to manually copy `gcp_sql_operator.py` and its dependencies to the Composer `dags` folder following the instruction [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-local).

Comment: Hi @Feng, actually I wanted to execute SELECT query which I can't do using cloudsqlqueryoperator. I decided to use cloudsqldatabasehook instead to get connection object and had plans to execute select query by other ways. However in order to use cloudsqldatabasehook, when I try to import it as -
from airflow.contrib.hooks.gcp_sql_hook import CloudSqlDatabaseHook
I get error "cannot import name CloudSqlDatabaseHook" but I can import cloudsqlhook another class from same gcp_sql_hook.py file.

Comment: If you look at the gcp_sql_hook.py inside Airflow 1.10.1 (https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.1/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_sql_hook.py), you'll notice that CloudSqlDatabaseHook class is not included (it is, on the other hand, available in 1.10.2).

Comment: Airflow 1.10.2 is now available in Composer. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions#new_environments) is the list of supported versions.